# Odd equidissection of semisquare

Tags: tag-removed

Is it possible to cut the quadrilateral (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (2,2) into an odd number of triangles of the same area?

Comment: This question would be more suitable for Mathematics StackExchange

Comment: Seems fine for MathOverflow, since the only answer we have so far quotes a recent research paper (and implies that one cannot give an elementary answer by exhibiting such a dissection, because such a dissection is impossible).

Answer (score 9):

According to a result by Kasimatis and Stein quoted in the paper [Equidissections of kite-shaped quadrilaterals](https://msp.org/involve/2009/2-1/involve-v2-n1-p07-p.pdf), the answer should be *no*. The convex hull of $((0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(a,a))$, $Q(a)$ in their notation, here with $a=2$, has $2$-adic valuation $\nu_2(a)=\nu_2(2)=1>-1$, which implies that only even equidissections are possible (see Theorem (i) in Section 2).

Comment: Does this build upon Monsky's theorem (the one about dissecting a square into triangles, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem)?

Comment: Yes it seems everything started from Monsky's theorem... a very beautiful result indeed